# Can Spacetime interval be positive between two objects or events?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

We know that spacetime interval can be negative like if I am watching a star far away or it could be 0 like if it I an watching a guy sitting next to me but can it be Positive?

Comment: doesn't [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_intervals_in_flat_space) answer this question?

Comment: Keep in mind that the sign of the interval depends on the convention you are using. Positive interval could be either space-like or time-like depending on who you ask. Much better to use 'space-like' and 'time-like' to facilitate communications across readers of different books. P.S. *Of course* the negative trace convention is better and is used by all right-thinking people.

Answer (score 1):

The interval does not depend solely on the space separation $\Delta r$ between the events. It depends also on their time separation $\Delta t$. So yes, it can be positive, negative or zero, depending on the relation between $\Delta t$ and $\Delta r$

Comment: I mean to say that is there any place where we can see that the spacetime interval  is positive???